# Classic Elastic Load balancer always OutOfService

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I configured 2 ELBs. Classic and application.
The listener is configured to do the same - listen on Port 80, HTTP.

THe classic ELB shows always OutOfService.
The application ELB shows healthy.

THe Security Group is the same. THe port is the same. THe protocol is the same.

Any ideas how to debug, what could be the problem?

---

### Classic

[image: Classic]

[image]

---

### Application

[image: Application]

[image: Applicaion-ping]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your instances are failing the health checks.
Amazon suggests a few things to help troubleshoot issue, have you gone over all items listed here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html